# How to notify superview of subview removal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I added a custom UIView to a UIViewController and after some code in the view, I want to remove this view from the UIViewController, but I am not sure how to notify the UIViewController of the UIView's removal.

I am using this method to exit from within the UIView

```
-(void)exit{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Do I need to set a listener? Any help is appreciated

---

**I posted a detailed solution. Thanks Rage, Bill L, and FreeNickname**

Comment: Should a view remove itself from superView, would it be easy if superView removes it's subview. That way you have more control over what you do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about that. In my case I am removing the subView based on a conditional in the subview. I believe in that situation I would need a listener or an NSNotification for the conditional from the subview in my superview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is not convenient to write a code as a comment, I'll write it as an answer. This answer illustrates what @Rage suggested in his answer.

First, you create a `@protocol` for your `CustomView` and add a `delegate` for it. You declare that the `delegate` should conform to this protocol. Then in your ViewController you implement your protocol and set ViewController as a delegate of your CustomView.

Like so:

**CustomView.h:**

```
@protocol CustomViewDelegate<NSObject>

//You can also declare it as @optional. In this case your delegate can
//ignore this method. And when you call it, you have to check, whether 
//your delegate implements it or not.
-(void)viewWasRemoved:(UIView *)view

@end

@interface CustomView: UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**CustomView.m:**

```
@implementation CustomView

-(void)exit {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    //if your method is NOT @optional:
    [self.delegate  viewWasRemoved:self];

    //if it IS @optional:
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWasRemoved:)]) {
        [self.delegate viewWasRemoved:self];
    }
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface ViewController()<CustomViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)someMethod {
    self.customView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWasRemoved:(UIView *)view {
    //Whatever
}

@end
```

Comment: This answer really clears up protocol for me. Very efficient and useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use delegation. Add a protocol to your custom View which implements a method to notify the removal of the subview.
Make the View controller the delegate while adding the custom view. In your custom class call the delegate method right before `[self removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 2):

Set up a delegate for it, with a method called `viewWasRemoved:` or something similar. Set your view's delegate to be the ViewController you want to notify, and then in your exit method, call `[self.delegate viewWasRemoved:self];`, which will then kick off the `viewWasRemoved:` method in your ViewController, where you can do any relevant work you need to do once the view is removed.

Answer (score 0):

**I'll post a detailed solution in case it helps anyone out, or if anyone can offer any pointers. Thanks Rage, Bill L, and FreeNickname:**

The answer is to use delegation

First I imported the superview to the .h of my subview:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Then I add a delegate id to the same file:

```
@property (weak) id delegate;
```

Then when initializing the custom UIView in the superview, I set the delegate:

```
 CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
 view.delegate = self;
```

I add this method in the superview for a callback:

```
- (void) viewWasRemoved: (UIView *) view{
    NSLog(@"removed");
}
```

Then finally call the method in my subView:

```
-(void)exit{
    [self.delegate viewWasRemoved:self];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Never use `retain` for delegates (by the way, why `retain`, and not `strong`? ARC has been around for a while now). Only use `weak`. Because there is a high probability that your delegate holds a strong reference to your object. Like ViewController holds a strong reference to your view. If the view also holds a strong reference to the VC, it creates a retain-cycle and causes a memory leak.

Comment: Also, if I understood you correctly, you added `#import "ViewController.h"` to the subview header file. Why?

Comment: okay thanks, i used weak instead, edited to fix my mistake. I need to import `ViewController.h` in order to refer to the method `[self.delegate viewWasRemoved:self]`

Comment: this is not how you do it :) What if you want to use your custom view in another ViewController? You can't import a header for every file where you're going to use you CustomView into your CustomView's header. It's done using protocols (as Rage suggested). It's not convenient to write code as a comment, so I'll write it as an answer in a moment.